# How do I check if a regular expression is matched by no string?

Tags: java, regex

From theoretical computer science we know that the problem of determining whether a regular language is empty is decidable.

Is there a way to check whether a Java regular expression denotes the empty language, or in other words, whether no string exists that matches it?

Note that I'm NOT asking whether a regular expression *exists* that matches nothing nor *what* such a regular expression is. I know that there are, and that they are infinite. I'm asking how do I *recognize* them.

Comment: Java's regular expressions (and a lot of REs in other languages as well) are not academic regular expressions - they are superset and are much more powerful. E.g. they have lookaheads and backreferences which make languages described by regexps non-regular.

Comment: I might be wrong (I'm rusty on this topic), but since, as @yeputons said, Java's so-called "regular expressions" are in fact [neither regular nor context-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Patterns_for_non-regular_languages), they are undecidable. I believe their undecidability makes the answer to your question "No, it's not possible."